# WPF Slider Thumb, hide thumb by default and fade in on slider mouse over

Tags: c#, wpf, slider

I'm new to WPF and I am attempting to make a progress bar similar to the one on

[image: SoundCloud]

I have no trouble creating this part, however am with the mouse over part.

[image: MouseOver]

Does anyone have some XAML to assist me with the triggers?

Thank you :)

Comment: Have you made any progress with it so far? Any code to show? Or are you just hoping someone will do your work for you?

Comment: This isn't _work_ this is just personal project. I have [this](http://pastebin.com/D8gZsHu3). However no. I haven't made any progress.

Comment: Well the idea of stack overflow is to ask specific programming related questions, not to try and offload tasks to other developers to do for you. Make an attempt at solving the problem yourself and if you get stuck and have a specific question, you can come here for help.